# How to create a user and send an invitation in node.js api

Tags: node.js, postgresql, security, typeorm, nodemailer

In an app where users aren't signed up by themselves but are instead created (name, email input) by existing users and sent an invitation email with link to password reset. Do I create a user and generate a random placeholder password like this:

```
const newUser = {
  name: input.name,
  email: input.email,
  password: generateAndHashRandomPassword()
}

await User.create(newUser)

await sendEmail(newUser.email)
```

Or is there a best practice / standard / simpler other method to achieve this functionality?

The password reset also changed the `isActive` property on user model to `true` from default before password change being `false`